# Django F expression with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

I want to order model using F expression.

On same model (idmm), `long` attribute is working

```
ExpressionWrapper(
        (lat - Func(F('long'), function='x')),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
```

but on foreign model (foreign) with accessor idmm__long

```
ExpressionWrapper(
        (lat - Func(F('idmm__long'), function='x')),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
```

it is not working.

Running this query `foreing.objects.all()[0].idmm.long` in shell is working fine.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Error i get is: "TypeError: a float is required"

Comment: Define "it is not working"

Comment: sorry, i get "TypeError: a float is required"

Comment: Does your foreign key has `null = True`?

Comment: No, should it have?